# How to extract Key Value fields from Json string in Splunk

Tags: json, splunk, text-extraction

I have json format Splunk search results like below :

```
"{
    "Name": "RUNQDATA",
    "RunId": "2021021701",
    "Details": <{
        "RunQID": "796562",
        "TQID": "796562",
        "Ent": {
            "NAME": "Inv",
            "Store": {
                "NAME": "FSW",
                "TYPE": "QUEUE",
                "USERNAME": "abc"
            }
        },
        "ADD_COUNT": "5740",
        "UPDATE_COUNT": "0",
        "DELETE_COUNT": "0"
    }>,
    "status": "success",
}"
```

How can I extract the fields like ADD_COUNT or UPDATE_COUNT from this ? I tried spath & other options , however not able to get the required results. Probably because the json contains <>.

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed.  If the angle brackets are removed then the `spath` command will parse the whole thing.  The `spath` command doesn't handle malformed JSON.

If you can't change the format of the event then you'll have to use the `rex` command to extract the fields as in this run-anywhere example

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="{
    \"Name\": \"RUNQDATA\",
    \"RunId\": \"2021021701\",
    \"Details\": <{
        \"RunQID\": \"796562\",
        \"TQID\": \"796562\",
        \"Ent\": {
            \"NAME\": \"Inv\",
            \"Store\": {
                \"NAME\": \"FSW\",
                \"TYPE\": \"QUEUE\",
                \"USERNAME\": \"abc\"
            }
        },
        \"ADD_COUNT\": \"5740\",
        \"UPDATE_COUNT\": \"0\",
        \"DELETE_COUNT\": \"0\"
    }>,
    \"status\": \"success\",
}"
| rex "UPDATE_COUNT\": \"(?<UPDATE_COUNT>\d+)"
| rex "DELETE_COUNT\": \"(?<DELETE_COUNT>\d+)"
```